# Maven plugin for calling an external JAR during project build phase

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I would like to ask for some help related to the following scenario: namely, I have a main Java project (a Java web application deployable via Tomcat server) whose compiled classes I analyze and validate against the application database via a second standalone Java program (callable from the command line) - both projects were created using Maven. Both of these projects are working without any problem when invoked separately, however, I would now need to join them together.
Concretely, I am now looking for a possibility to join the 2 projects together as follows: when I am deploying the first application via Maven on the Tomcat server, I would like to invoke also the second application for checking the well-formed feature (i.e. validation against the application DB) of this application.
As I understand, this might be possible from Maven in a similar manner like for the other known plugins (*please see an example below*), but unfortunately I have not found yet any solution to the problem. Therefore, I would be interested in some recommendations related to the current topic. Thank you in advance for your help,
             Frantisek

[Link to sample plugin - Maven Javadoc plugin example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt9iQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that the ProjectB will be deployed to Tomcat
Include the the projectA into projectB as dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>yourgroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Before you put it in the ProjectB pom.xml, remember to Maven Install the ProjectA in local repository.

Please remember, this approach resolved the dependency problem. However, Invokde ProjectA from ProjectB is another matter you have to deal with.

One of the option is to unify them by some framework API, e.g. Spring. Making them running under same Spring instance.